# Update/Insert into View wia Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, sql-view

It occurred in my project that I had to extend an existing table with a few more columns. Unfortunately I can't alter or drop/recreate it, so I just chose to create another table with a 1:1-Relationship and merge them in a view with Insert/Update/Delete-Triggers.

So far, insert and Delete works, but I have my issues with the Update-Trigger. The success-message is even more confusing.

The View looks like this:

```
Create View [dbo].[JoinedGroups] as
SELECT [dbo].[MaterialGroups].[GroupID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[SupGroup_ID]
      ,[ExtGroup_ID]
  FROM [dbo].[MaterialGroups]
 left outer join [dbo].[MaterialGroups_Extend]
 ON [dbo].[MaterialGroups].[GroupID]=[dbo].[MaterialGroups_Extend].[GroupID]
```

As said the new additional Table isn't filled yet, that's the reason for the left outer join, but if you got a different idea, let me know it.

The Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTriggerJG] ON [dbo].[JoinedGroups]
INSTEAD OF Update
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MaterialGroups_Extend] E,inserted I WHERE E.[GroupID] = I.[GroupID])
BEGIN
   UPDATE [dbo].[MaterialGroups_Extend]
   SET [SupGroup_ID] = I.[SupGroup_ID]
      ,[ExtGroup_ID] = I.[ExtGroup_ID]
      FROM [Buran].[dbo].[MaterialGroups_Extend] E,inserted I
   WHERE E.[GroupID] = I.[GroupID]
END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[MaterialGroups_Extend]
           ([GroupID]
           ,[SupGroup_ID]
           ,[ExtGroup_ID])     
      SELECT [GroupID]
           ,[SupGroup_ID]
           ,[ExtGroup_ID]
      FROM inserted
      END
   UPDATE [dbo].[MaterialGroups]
   SET [dbo].[MaterialGroups].[Name] = I.Name
   FROM [dbo].[MaterialGroups],inserted I
   WHERE [dbo].[MaterialGroups].[GroupID] = I.[GroupID]
```

A statement like:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[JoinedGroups]
   SET 
      [SupGroup_ID] = 1
      ,[ExtGroup_ID] = 1
```

Gives the following output:

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(23 row(s) affected)

(23 row(s) affected)
```

Which is kinda interesting:
[MaterialGroups] contains 23 rows of data
[MaterialGroups_Extend] contains 2 rows of data
The view has 23 as well.

But why isn't anything inserted? Am I doing something wrong or have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to rewrite your trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTriggerJG] ON [dbo].[JoinedGroups]
INSTEAD OF Update
AS
begin
    update dbo.MaterialGroups_Extend set
        SupGroup_ID = I.SupGroup_ID,
        ExtGroup_ID = I.ExtGroup_ID
    from dbo.MaterialGroups_Extend as E
        inner join inserted I on I.GroupID = E.GroupID

    insert into dbo.MaterialGroups_Extend
    (
        GroupID,
        SupGroup_ID,
        ExtGroup_ID
    )     
    select
        GroupID,
        SupGroup_ID,
        ExtGroup_ID,
    from inserted as i
    where
        not exists
        (
             select *
             from dbo.MaterialGroups_Extend as E
             where E.GroupID = I.GroupID
        )

    update dbo.MaterialGroups set
        Name = I.Name
    from dbo.MaterialGroups as MG
        inner join inserted I on I.GroupID = MG.GroupID
end
```

Comment: An interesting solution, I try it right now, just a minute...
May I ask some questions?
- Why did you go for an inner join, instead of a regular list of tables like I did? I have some more experience with Oracle, there the performance is better if no joins are used.
- Do you know why my solution isn't working? Is it just the order or did I oversee anything?